# .net 4.5 razor - pass local variable to partial

Tags: .net, razor

I'd like to be able to pass a variable defined in one template to another, which is included by the first template:

Template 1:

```
@{string datetype= "beforethisyear"}
@RenderPage("Template2.cshtml", datetype)
```

Template 2:

```
<input type="text" data-datetype="@datetype"/>
```

Unfortunately, this yields an error in Template 2:

```
"The name 'datetype' does not exist in the current context"
```

Is there a way to pass the variable without binding it to a model first?

Comment: Datepicker refers to what? is it a control?

Comment: sorry, I copy-pasted that. fix'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ViewBag:

Template1:

```
@{ ViewBag.DateType = "beforethisyear"; }
```

Template2:

```
<input type="text" data-datetype="@ViewBag.DateType"/>
```

This is just what the ViewBag is for - passing **view-only** data around. Note that if the data you are passing is actually something that is or should be part of the data model then you should really use a property of the Model for it. Given the names of your variables I'm guessing that it *should* be part of the model. Note that Model isn't necessarily your data class (i.e. an Entity representing a row in a table), a Model for a View in a MVC is anything that conceptually represents the data in that View.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you could use the `ViewBag` for this

```
@{ViewBag.Datetype = "beforethisyear"}
```

and

```
<input type="text" data-datetype="@ViewBag.Datetype"/>
```